# why max value of n_component depends upon n_classes in LDA()

Tags: feature-selection

[image]

According to sklearn LDA() documentation, max n_components value depend upon the classes the data have. but I am unable to understand why it can't be more than no. of classes when features are more. Why it's depends upon no. of classes.

can anyone explain me or may be share some article which can explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because LDA ([Linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)) finds separating hyperplanes between classes. Projection onto these hyperplanes can yield dimension reduction as well. An intuitive way to think of it is that, to separate two classes, you find one hyperplane, i.e. one discriminant function is enough. To separate $n$ classes, $n-1$ discriminant functions will be enough.

From a mathematical perspective, since the matrix $\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma_b$ is of rank at most $n-1$, and the scatter coefficient in LDA is maximized by the eigenvectors (hyperplanes) of this matrix, you can obtain at most $n-1$ of them. Related section in wiki is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#/Multiclass_LDA).

Comment: okay...got it thanks 